# Regex - How can I exclude expressions with duplicated characters

Tags: regex

I am awful trying to figure out Regex and I was wondering who I could achieve the following scenario...

Let's say my input is something like this.

```
|1 |2 ||3 ||312 |213
```

I would like to have a Regex that matches only the occurrences with one '|'. So basically, I want to match any text that contains one '|' and any amount of numbers after it...

I tried this one: `[\|][0-9]+` but obviously it is also giving me ||3 and ||312 as matches.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Why you need to use regex to check the existence of "||"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negative lookbehind assertion.

```
(?<!\|)\|[0-9]+
```

`(?<!\|)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match `\|[0-9]+` won't be preceded by a pipe character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cA0xY0/1)

Comment: in js, `(?:^|[^|])(\|[0-9]+)` . Get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: Both? Who is the another one?  I'm the answerer as well as I'm the commenter.

Comment: I meant both expressions were working as I was expecting :)